# Copy an XML node to another file

Tags: php, xml

I am currently using the below PHP code to get an 'imagepath',  then I loop through the XML to delete the node that has this path.

```
<?php       
$id = $_GET['imagepath'];       
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('newcoke.xml');
$root   = $xmldoc->documentElement;
$fnode  = $root->firstChild;

$items = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('flight');
foreach ($items as $item){
    $node = $item->getElementsByTagName('imagepath')->item(0);
    if ($node->nodeValue == $id){
        $node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);            
    }
}
$xmldoc->save('newXmlFile.xml');
?>
```

I have been trying it for hours to then somehow copy the deleted node and save it into a new XML file with the same structure that exists called 'deleted'. Can anybody help?

This is the structure of the xml :

```
<ArrivingFlights>
     <flight>
        <to>Ger</to>
        <from>Mammy xx</from>
        <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>08:00</time>
        <date>21/12/15</date>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <to>Ciara</to>
        <from>Vikki xx</from>
        <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>11:00</time>
        <date>17/12/15</date>
    </flight>
</ArrivingFlights>
```

Comment: can you show us some sample xml

Comment: @zan Ive made an edit. thanks

Comment: Can you please also provide an example of this "same structure that exists called 'deleted'" so we can see which part of the structure you want to copy?

Comment: If you look at the sample XML in my question, my php file could delete that whole first node so the deleted xml will then be :

  <flight>
        <to>Ger</to>
        <from>Mammy xx</from>
        <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
        <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
        <time>08:00</time>
        <date>21/12/15</date>
    </flight>

Comment: The deleted.xml will contain everything in the <fight> node that was deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DOMNode::removeChild](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) returns the node it just has removed; this object is still valid ...for the DOM istance it has been removed from.
To use it in another DOM you have to [import](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) it, before appending it to some element/node in that other DOM instance.

```
if ($node->nodeValue == $id){
    $rn = $node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);
    $deletedFlight = $otherDom->importNode($rn, true); // make a deep-copy for the other DOM
    $otherDom->documentElement->appendChild($deletedFlight);
}
```

...or you can pass $rn to [DOMDocument::saveXML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) and append the return value to a file via `file_put_contents(..,.., FILE_APPEND)`. The resulting file would look like

```
<flight>
    <to>Ger</to>
    <from>Mammy xx</from>
    <imagepath>0002.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>08:00</time>
    <date>21/12/15</date>
</flight>
<flight>
    <to>Ciara</to>
    <from>Vikki xx</from>
    <imagepath>0003.jpg</imagepath>
    <templateStyle>template1</templateStyle>
    <time>11:00</time>
    <date>17/12/15</date>
</flight>
```

which is not valid XML (more than one top-level element) ...but ... 
You can import that file as an entity into a valid XML document.
That way (being a little careful) you could get rid of the second DOM and the time and memory it takes to build it.

Comment: Im getting these errors 
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Document is empty in file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/coke/deleted.xml, line: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coke\ApproveImage.php on line 11

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/coke/deleted.xml, line: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coke\ApproveImage.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\coke\ApproveImage.php on line 13

Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\coke\ApproveImage.php on line 22

Comment: Oh nevermind it needed content to apend, thanks mate